# Solidity: Dedupping string keys inside a pure function

Tags: solidity

I am trying to define a mapping to use inside a function as a means of quickly determining whether a key exists.  I realize I could also use an array and loop thorugh it but that seems like it might get expensive.  But that you can't create mappings dynamically, and if I create a state variable for the purpose, then I have the problem of clearing state between calls to this function which makes it pricey.

Here is what I was tyring to do, any suggestions for the most efficient method to dedupe a set of strings inside a pure function?

```
function dedupe(string[] memory keys) public pure returns(string[] memory) {
        string[] memory deduped;
        mapping(string=>bool) map;
        string memory ikey;
        for(uint i=0; i<keys.length; i++) {
            ikey = keys[i];
            if (!map[ikey]) {
                map[ikey]=true;
                deduped.push(ikey);
            }
        }
        return deduped;
    }
```